# What's the most terse way to write a bunch of String.replaceAll("thing1", "thing2"); statements?

Tags: java

I feel like I could do something with linked lists, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

~Sigh~ I would love this in python.  Would just use dictionaries.

Thanks a lot,
statue

Comment: Please give more information, or your question is very likely to be closed as "not a real question". It's not at all clear where Python dictionaries come in here either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String strOutput = src.replace("foo","foo2").replace("bar","bar2");
```

or, if you have many more replacements, store them in an array:

```
//array to hold replacements
String[][] replacements = {{"foo", "foo2"}, 
                           {"bar", "bar2"}};

//loop over the array and replace
for(String[] replacement: replacements) {
    src = src.replace(replacement[0], replacement[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the second is what I was looking for.  I just couldn't think of a concise way to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to do a bunch of replacements after another on the same string (replace a by b, c by d etc...)

you could do that in a map like this

```
String toreplace = ...

Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
replacments.put("A","B");
replacments.put("C","D");
replacments.put("D","E");

for (Entry curReplacement : replacments.entryMap())
{
 toReplace.replaceAll(curReplacement.getKey(),curReplacement.getValue())
}
```

Be carfeul though. You cannot predict the order of replacements, as soon as you have overlapping replacments (e.g. replace a by b and b by c) you cannot predict the outcome (in this case an OrderedHashMap would be the better solution)